# AngularJS yo grunt serve problems resolving templates

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I swapped to yo angular to help with my SPA. In the most part it works fine. I had to update a lot of packages and in some places remove depreciated versions.
The problem I have now is that while using `grunt serve` there are a few references that are either missing or pointing to the wrong directory.

The first one of these is my custom **datepicker** control template. It overrides the bootstrap version with my own. Like I have mentioned, when built and deployed it works fine, but when testing it uses the default bootstrap template.

The second issue is with **font-awesome**. Same issue, when built and deployed it works fine. But when testing it doesn't find the files.

My Grunt file looks like this:

```
// Generated on 2017-12-03 using generator-angular 0.16.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn'
  });

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');
  var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/app/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'newer:jscs:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'newer:jscs:test', 'karma']
      },
      sass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              modRewrite(['!\\.html|\\.js|\\.svg|\\.css|\\.png$ /index.html [L]']),                        
              serveStatic('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                serveStatic('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                serveStatic('./app/styles')
              ),
              serveStatic(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              serveStatic('.tmp'),
              serveStatic('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                serveStatic('./bower_components')
              ),
              serveStatic(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          //'<%= yeoman.app %>/app/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par
    jscs: {
      options: {
        config: '.jscsrc'
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    postcss: {
      options: {
        processors: [
          require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['last 1 version']})
        ]
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          map: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject my components into index.html
    injector: {
      options: {
        template: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
      },
      scripts: {
        options: {
          transform: function (filePath) {
              return '<script src="' + filePath.replace('/src/', '') + '"></script>';
          }
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/app/app.module.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/app/**/*module.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/app/**/*constants.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/app/**/*service.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/app/**/*routes.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/app/**/*.js'
          ]
        }
      },
      styles: {
        options: {
          transform: function (filePath) {
              return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '') + '" />';
          }
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html': [
            '.tmp/styles/**/*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        exclude: [
          /jquery/,
          /markerclustererplus/,
          /google-maps-utility-library-v3-/,
          /js-rich-marker/,
          /angular-mocks/,
          /bootstrap-sass-official/          
        ],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      },
      test: {
        devDependencies: true,
        src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
        fileTypes:{
          js: {
            block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
              detect: {
                js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
              },              
              replace: {
                js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }, 

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    sass: {
      options: {
          includePaths: [
              'bower_components'
          ]
      },
      dist: {
          files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
              src: ['*.scss'],
              dest: '.tmp/styles',
              ext: '.css'
          }]
      },
      server: {
          files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
              src: ['*.scss'],
              dest: '.tmp/styles',
              ext: '.css'
          }]
      }
  },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>//images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
        ],
        patterns: {
          js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/app/app.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/app/app'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    ngtemplates: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          module: 'sapphire',
          htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
          usemin: 'scripts/scripts.js'
        },
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        src: [
          'app/**/*.html',
          'uib/**/*.html'
        ],
        dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js'
      }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '*.html',
            'web.config',
            '/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/',
          src: '*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts'
        },
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/',
          src: '*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'sass:server',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'sass',
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'injector',
      'concurrent:server',
      'postcss:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'injector',
    'concurrent:test',
    'postcss',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'injector',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'postcss',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    //'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'newer:jscs',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

And my source **index.html** file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title ng-bind="'Sapphire | ' + $state.current.data.pageTitle"></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <base href="/">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ng-notify/src/styles/ng-notify.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/core.css -->
  <!-- injector:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/core.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/print.css" />
  <!-- endinjector -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="sapphire" ng-controller="IdleController">
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy"></script> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

  <div class="cssload" ajax-loader>
    <div class="cssload-spin-box"></div>
  </div>

  <div snow="{ 'start': '01/12', end: '15/01' }" options="$options">
    <div class="page-header" ng-include="'app/includes/header.html'"></div>
    <section class="page metro" ui-view metro ng-if="!forbidden"></section>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-cloak ng-if="forbidden">
      <p>
        </script>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBj2GP_dnRkgrupIRMqe3nI8ZJlT4wmYPU'></script>

  <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-barcode/dist/angular-barcode.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-simple-cache/dist/simpleCache.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-mask/dist/mask.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/newrelic-timing/newrelic-timing.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/newrelic-timing/newrelic-timing-angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-idle/angular-idle.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/ng-notify/src/scripts/ng-notify.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/vkbeautify/vkBeautify.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:js({.tmp,src}) scripts/scripts.js -->
  <!-- injector:js -->
  <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
  <!-- removed for brevity -->
  <!-- endinjector -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
</body>

</html>
```

As I am new to the angular generator, there have been some issues getting things to work, but like i have mentioned most of it is fine.
I know there is a lot of code there but I am hoping that someone has had a similar issue and know exactly what the solution is.